# postfix и множество сетевых интерфейсов

Tags: linux, centos, администрирование, postfix

Приветствую!

Существуют несколько серверов на centos 6 с одинаковой сетевой конфигурацией и одинаковыми конфигами postfix (v2.11.7) с поправками на имена хостов. При такой конфигурации большинство хостов шлёт почту с адреса на bond0 (в данном примере 192.168.2.191), но есть пара хостов, которые настырно продолжают слать почту с eth1 (192.168.1.1) что не правильно. Есть ли какое-то логичное объяснение этому феномену? Примеры конфигов ниже.

P.S. Мне важно именно объяснение почему так происходит, а не совет использовать `smtp_bind_address` в конфиге postfix.

ip a:

```
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP qlen 1000
        link/ether 19:62:ad:f3:81:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
        link/ether 19:62:ad:f3:81:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 192.168.1.1/30 brd 192.168.1.3 scope global eth1
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP qlen 1000
        link/ether 19:62:ad:f3:81:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
        link/ether 19:62:ad:f3:81:d3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    6: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
        link/ether 19:62:ad:f3:81:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 192.168.2.191/22 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global bond0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    7: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
        link/void 
    8: bond0.101@bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
        link/ether 19:62:ad:f3:81:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 77.1.14.155/24 brd 77.1.14.255 scope global bond0.101
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

/etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
    queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
    command_directory = /usr/sbin
    daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
    data_directory = /var/lib/postfix

    myhostname = test-host-1.domain.local
    mydomain = domain.local
    myorigin = $myhostname

    inet_interfaces = localhost, 192.168.2.191
    inet_protocols = ipv4

    mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost

    unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
    mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8

    relay_domains = $mydestination

    alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
    alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
    home_mailbox = Maildir/
    debug_peer_level = 2
    debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

    sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
    newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
    mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
    manpage_directory = /usr/share/man

    maximal_backoff_time = 6h
    maximal_queue_lifetime = 3d
    bounce_queue_lifetime = $maximal_queue_lifetime
    message_size_limit = 26214400
    mailbox_size_limit = 134217728
    virtual_mailbox_limit = $mailbox_size_limit
    in_flow_delay = 1
    allow_min_user = yes

    relayhost = my-own-relay.domain.local

    smtpd_helo_required = yes

    smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks
        reject_unauth_destination

    html_directory = no
    setgid_group = postdrop
    mail_owner = postfix
```

Comment: маршруты разные?

Comment: relayhost у всех прописан и у всех одинаковый?

Comment: @defrag да, одинаковый.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вы гений :) действительно, отчасти тут дело в маршрутизации. Если интересно, то поясню: все эти хосты - рассадник openvz контейнеров, и так уж получилось, что relay'и находятся на некоторых из них, так вот все эти хосты почему-то ходят до своих контейнеров не с того интерфейса, с которого надо бы. Теперь надо подумать как это исправить, тут много routes и rules , так что это будет не очень просто :(